# Error during WebSocket handshake with user endpoint once Django Channels app is deployed

Tags: django, heroku, websocket, reverse-proxy, django-channels

I'm trying to set up a websocket connection at the user level in my django app for receiving notifications. prod is https so need to use wss.

Here is the js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

socket = new WebSocket("wss://" + window.location.host + "/user_id/");
var $notifications = $('.notifications');
var $notificationList = $('.dropdown-menu.notification-list');

$notifications.click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('newNotification')
});

socket.onmessage = function(e) {

// notification stuff

// Call onopen directly if socket is already open
if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) socket.onopen();

}
```

I've implemented django-channels in settings.py like this:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts":[ENV_STR("REDIS_URL")]
        },
        "ROUTING": "project.routing.channel_routing",
     },
}
```

routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route
from community.consumers import ws_add, ws_disconnect

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_add),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]
```

locally, this handshakes just fine.

```
2017-04-16 16:37:04,108 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-04-16 16:37:04,109 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-04-16 16:37:04,109 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-04-16 16:37:04,110 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-04-16 16:37:04,111 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2017-04-16 16:37:04,112 - INFO - server - Using busy-loop synchronous mode on channel layer
2017-04-16 16:37:04,112 - INFO - server - Listening on endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
[2017/04/16 16:37:22] HTTP GET / 200 [0.55, 127.0.0.1:60129]
[2017/04/16 16:37:23] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /user_id/ [127.0.0.1:60136]
[2017/04/16 16:37:23] WebSocket CONNECT /user_id/ [127.0.0.1:60136]
[2017/04/16 16:37:25] HTTP GET /user/test10 200 [0.47, 127.0.0.1:60129]
[2017/04/16 16:37:25] WebSocket DISCONNECT /user_id/ [127.0.0.1:60136]
[2017/04/16 16:37:26] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /user_id/ [127.0.0.1:60153]
[2017/04/16 16:37:26] WebSocket CONNECT /user_id/ [127.0.0.1:60153]
```

However, now that the app has been deployed to Heroku, the /_user_id/ endpoint is returning 404, and I'm getting ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME when it should be a valid endpoint:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/user_id/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404.
```

As I'm continuing to research it seems like this server config can't actually support websockets in prod. Current Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi:application --log-file -
worker: python manage.py runworker -v2
```

I spent a few hrs looking at converting the app to asgi and using Daphne, although since the project is python 2.7 that's a difficult conversion (not to mention seems to require a different static file implementation)

Comment: The logs and code say `/user_id/`, but the error shows `/user/user_id/`?

Comment: hey robert sorry that's a copy-paste mistake from trying another endpoint. i've edited the post. the err's also getting thrown with /user_id/

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy of some kind running in front of your app server?

Comment: at the moment I've deployed it to heroku and am working on getting it running there. I found this description which suggests there likely is: "Heroku runs DNS servers that point "appname.heroku.com" domains to a subset of their front-end reverse proxies, or you can setup a custom subdomain with a CNAME that points to proxy.heroku.com (which in turn resolves to the reverse proxy IPs), or a root domain with A records pointing directly to Heroku's reverse proxies. Multiple IPs (currently 3) will be returned to provide failover in case one or more of the reverse proxy servers is down."